# 3D plot difference Matlab and Wolfram

Tags: matlab, 3d, wolfram-alpha

I'm trying to plot the function $z = 6x^2 - 4x^2y^2$ in Matlab. The code I'm using for this in matlab is the one below, also the plot is shown:

```
v = [-2:0.1:2];
w = [-2:0.1:2];
[X,Y] = meshgrid(v,w);
Z = 6*X.^2-4*X.^2*Y.^2;
figure(3);
surf(X,Y,Z)
```

[image: ù]

Now I when I plot this same function in Wolram Alpha I'm getting something different and I can't figure it out why. Here is the plot on Wolfram: [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3d%20plot%206x%5E2-4x%5E2y%5E2)

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the Matlab-syntax anymore but that plot is wrong (and W|A is right); $z = 6x^2 - 4x^2y^2$ is not a parabolic cylinder.

Comment: How can you get values of $-580$ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you have some problems with 3D plots in Matlab, it is often helpful to use different grids for $x$ and $y$. For example, if you change your code as `v = [-2:0.1:3];`, you will have a helpful error message: `Error using *. Incorrect dimensions for matrix multiplication.` It means that you have matrix multiplication in your equation and not the element-wise. Try `Z = 6*X.^2-4*X.^2.*Y.^2`.

Comment: Thanks! That was indeed the issue. Forgot one "." in the equation.